# Android DatePicker and DateFormat with Output Format as 'mm-dd-yyyy'

Tags: java, android, sql, datetime, timestamp

This is my datepicker function.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    String rideDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());
}
```

Here the output will be in the format
`'m/d/yy'`. That is, for example:  `'3/9/20'` for `9th march 2020`.

I want a output like `'mm-dd-yyyy'`. That is, for example: `'03-09-2020` for `9th march 2020'`.

What are the ways for achieving this result?

Comment: Have you tried to use different pre-built formats like `DateFormat.FULL` or `DateFormat.MEDIUM`? However, my advice is: **Use [`java.time`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) if possible and/or use the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Sample usage

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())
```